# Moving secure files out of assets to a secure folder

Tags: php, silverstripe

By default (and as far as I know this can't be changed) files are uploaded to /assets at all times and folders beneath assets. I have a secure set of files that need to be uploaded, as I can't find a way to change where they are uploaded to, I figured on after write I could try and move the file to a secure directory. I have tried using

```
move_uploaded_file($file->Name, '\/secret\/');
```

to move the file to a root folder called 'secret' but this doesn't seem to change anything. Perhaps I am doing something wrong on that behalf or it just doesn't work. If anyone has done this before or knows how, I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to escape slashes in single-quoted strings: use ` '/secret/' ` instead. Then, I don't know _silverstripe_, but what is the value of `$file->Name`: it is the name OR the filePath?

Comment: $file->Name in this case is just the file name with hyphens for spaces. The path is available with $file->Filename.

Comment: try to use `->Filename` instead of `->File`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SilverStripe it is not currently possible to move a CMS controlled file or folder outside of the `assets` folder.

An alternative is to use the [Secure Assets module](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-secureassets) to add access restrictions to folders that mirror the access restrictions of `SiteTree` pages.

Once this module is installed you can [change the permissions of your secure folder](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-secureassets/blob/master/docs/en/userguide/index.md) so that only certain logged in users can access the folder and the files in it.